# Python Tkinter .jpeg Image not displaying -- TclError

Tags: python, image, class, tkinter, canopy

I'm attempting to add a `.jpeg` image to my GUI while it has several other widgets.

With my code, I can display the image in a separate `Tkinter` window when I use the following command:

`#self.label = Label(image = self.img)`

However, whenever I try to add the image to the original `Tkinter` window, I get the error seen below my code. The way I tried to add it to the original Tkinter window is:

`#self.label = Label(frame, image = self.img)`

## Replicating the error

Oddly enough, when I try to replicate the error in a shorter version of the code (such as directly below), it works. HOWEVER! To replicate the error in the shortened code, you need to create a different error first. Example: Replace `text = "Try"` with `text = "%s" %yikes` (because there is no variable `yikes` it will give you an error). After you change the code back to the EXACT way it was before, it produces the error I've descried below (`TclError: image "pyimage__" doesn't exit`). At the very bottom, I've included  the entire class since I'm having difficulty consistently replicating the issue. I'm using Python 2.7 and Canopy 1.5.5.

## Shortened code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename, askdirectory

class App:

    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)

        self.button_left = Button(frame,text="< Previous Event")
        self.button_left.grid(row=1,column=0)
        self.button_right = Button(frame,text="Next Event >")
        self.button_right.grid(row=1,column=3)

       #Creating text for the UI indicating the number of leakage events
        w = Label(frame, text="Trying to Recreate error")
        w.grid(row=1,column=2)

        self.m = Canvas(frame,width=50,height=25)
        self.text_id = self.m.create_text(25,12.5, text="Try")
        self.m.grid(row=1,column=1)


        self.path = "C:\Carbonite\EL_36604.02_231694\EL_36604.02_231694_2015-06-15 10.39.57.jpeg"
        self.image = Image.open(self.path)
        self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
        #self.label = Label(image = self.img)
        self.label = Label(frame,image = self.img)
        self.label.image = self.img
        self.label.grid(row = 3, column = 0)
        frame.grid(row=0,column=0)

root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

## Error I receive in my program when I use the commented out method:

```
    TclError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Carbonite\Main_interface_file.py in <module>()
    136 
    137 root = Tk()
--> 138 app = App(root)
    139 root.mainloop()
    140 

C:\Carbonite\Main_interface_file.py in __init__(self, master)
     72         self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
     73         #self.label = Label(image = self.img)
---> 74         self.label = Label(frame,image = self.img)
     75         self.label.image = self.img
     76         self.label.grid(row=3, column = 0)

C:\Users\U10596\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.pyc in __init__(self, master, cnf, **kw)
   2585 
   2586         """
-> 2587         Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
   2588 
   2589 class Listbox(Widget, XView, YView):

C:\Users\U10596\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.pyc in __init__(self, master, widgetName, cnf, kw, extra)
   2084                 del cnf[k]
   2085         self.tk.call(
-> 2086             (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
   2087         for k, v in classes:
   2088             k.configure(self, v)

TclError: image "pyimage8" doesn't exist
```

## Almost entire Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np
from images_to_list import images_to_list
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename, askdirectory
#Creating a class that creates the UI
class App:

    def __init__(self, master):

        self.event_num = 1
        # Create a container
        frame = Frame(master)

        # Create 2 buttons (changes between leakage events
        self.button_left = Button(frame,text="< Previous Event",
                                        command=self.decrease)
        self.button_left.grid(row=1,column=0)
        self.button_right = Button(frame,text="Next Event >",
                                        command=self.increase)
        self.button_right.grid(row=1,column=3)

       #Creating text for the UI indicating the number of leakage events
        w = Label(frame, text="/  %s  " % len(tft))
        w.grid(row=1,column=2)

        #Display the number of the current event in the series
        self.m = Canvas(frame,width=50,height=25)
        self.text_id = self.m.create_text(25,12.5, text="%s" % (self.event_num+1))
        self.m.grid(row=1,column=1)

        #Creating the plot of voltage data
        self.fig = Figure()
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.fig.autofmt_xdate()
        import matplotlib.dates as mdates
        self.ax.fmt_xdata = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d')
        self.line, = self.ax.plot(tft[self.event_num],tf1[self.event_num],'.')
        self.line2, = self.ax.plot(tft[self.event_num],tf2[self.event_num],'.')
        self.ax.set_ylim([0,3.5])


        self.path = "C:\Carbonite\EL_36604.02_231694\EL_36604.02_231694_2015-06-15 10.39.57.jpeg"
        self.image = Image.open(self.path)
        self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
        #self.label = Label(image = self.img)
        self.label = Label(frame,image = self.img)
        self.label.image = self.img
        self.label.grid(row=3, column = 0)


        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig,master=master)
        self.canvas.show()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=1,column=0)
        frame.grid(row=0,column=0)

        #Creating a textbox to jump to event number
        self.textbox = Entry(frame,width=5)
        button1 = Button(frame, text='Go', command=self.letsgo) #Linking "Go" button with letsgo function to jump to event number
        self.textbox.grid(row=2,column=1)
        button1.grid(row=2,column=2)

    #function letsgo allows the user to jump to any event in the series    
    def letsgo(self):
        txt = self.textbox.get()
        try:
            self.event_num = int(txt)
        except ValueError:
            print "Opps! The number you enter needs to be an integer!"
        self.line.set_xdata(tft[self.event_num])
        self.line.set_ydata(tf1[self.event_num])
        self.line2.set_xdata(tft[self.event_num])
        self.line2.set_ydata(tf2[self.event_num])
        self.ax.set_xlim([min(tft[self.event_num]),max(tft[self.event_num])])
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.m.itemconfig(self.text_id, text="%s" % (self.event_num+1))

     #function decrease allows the user to use the decrease button                
    def decrease(self):
        if self.event_num == 0: #if statement accounts for if the user tries to see the event previous to the first one
            self.event_num = len(tft)-1
        else:
            self.event_num -= 1
        self.line.set_xdata(tft[self.event_num])
        self.line.set_ydata(tf1[self.event_num])
        self.line2.set_xdata(tft[self.event_num])
        self.line2.set_ydata(tf2[self.event_num])
        self.ax.set_xlim([min(tft[self.event_num]),max(tft[self.event_num])])
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.m.itemconfig(self.text_id, text="%s" % (self.event_num+1))

    #function increase allows the user to use the increase button            
    def increase(self):
        if self.event_num == len(tft)-1: #if statement accounts for if the user tries to see the event after the last one.
            self.event_num = 0
        else:
            self.event_num += 1        
        self.line.set_xdata(tft[self.event_num])
        self.line.set_ydata(tf1[self.event_num])
        self.line2.set_xdata(tft[self.event_num])
        self.line2.set_ydata(tf2[self.event_num])
        self.ax.set_xlim([min(tft[self.event_num]),max(tft[self.event_num])])
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.m.itemconfig(self.text_id, text="%s" % (self.event_num+1))





root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I suspect your posted code is a long way from being an mcve https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  It is unclear why you put the image on a canvas instead of directly on the frame.  If you do the latter, still the same problem?  I would try running the code directly with python instead of whatever IDE that you are using.  Also consider the error message.  pyimage7 is presumably self.img.  Add `print(self.img)` before the call to see what it really is.

Comment: I apologize, I had not seen that link before. I've edited my code to try make it more mcve (although I included most of the whole code at the bottom in case more context is needed). How would you put the image on the frame? As I said, I'm very new to Python.

Comment: See http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm for other ways to use image.  I repeat, run your code without Canopy to see if Canopy is the problem.  Try editing and running with IDLE editor, if you want, as IDLE is designed to be able to run tkinter programs, and there are no current reports of IDLE having a problem doing so.

Comment: I am currently using the format that link suggests for .jpg images. I've put the code directly in IDLE and I get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue!!

I used `askopenfilename()` in the very beginning of my code, which opened an extra `Tkinter` window. As a result, there were two `Tkinter` windows open and confused the program.

By sending everything to the first `Tk` window that was created (and removing the second), it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to grid the Frame.  When I add

```
frame.grid()
```

at the bottom of your `__init__` method it works fine.  I don't get an error when I run the code you posted, though.  It just doesn't display the label.  I wonder if this is some platform-dependent behavior.  I'm using python 2.7 on Yosemite 10.10.5.

EDIT: I've tried your extended example, and as expected, I don't see the behavior you.  I can change the code back and forth.  When it's incorrect, I get an error; when it's correct, it runs fine.

The behavior you describe must have something to do with Canopy.  The way the python interpreter works, it will compile the script to byte codes every time it runs; it doesn't know anything about what the script used to says.

Can you try running the suspect script from the command line?  Also, perhaps you should add the `canopy` tag to your question.

I don't use Canopy, so I don't think I can help you, but I'm leaving the answer here as background for someone who hopefully can.

Good luck.

Comment: I actually do grid the Frame in the original code. When I run the shortened example, it does work for me as well. I can't figure out why it's not working in my actual longer code (posted at the bottom).

Comment: Did you use my exact example of the error? Also, I've tried my actual code directly into Python IDLE and I get the same error. This makes me think that it is not a Canopy issue.

Comment: Yes, I used your exact example.  If it's happening in IDLE too, then it isn't a Canopy issue, but I can't reproduce it here.